# Remove before spacing after after section break

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a section break in my Word document and a title just after. I want to remove the spacing before my title but only after this section break. How is this achievable?

Edit:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKAmg.png)
I have a continuous section break (to lock the header). My title has a 60pt spacing before but I want my title to act like it is the start of a new page after this section break. So no spacing before my title after a section break.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Can you edit your quesion and add image(s) showing the problem?

Comment: Thanks! I added some details, hoping it's more clear.

Comment: Why not remove/reduce the 60pt spacing?

Comment: It's defined as a style. The document is a template with defined styles, margin, header, footer and people will be able to edit the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to View> Reveal Codes and see if there is not something you can change in the coding of the template?

Answer (score 0):

1. Place cursor in title you want to modify.
2. In the Styles pane on the home tab, right click on the title style and select Modify.
3. In the Modify Style dialog, un-check Automatically update. (This is the key to making sure you only affect this one instance of the style, not all instances.)
4. Hit OK.
5. Reduce spacing as desired.

One caveat - if there is a template applied, and the "Automatically update document styles" option is selected, the change you make **may** be undone when you save/re-open the document.  You'll want to double check after making the change to ensure what you did is still there.  If your change does revert back, the only way to keep the change permanently will be to un-check "Automatically update document styles".